# simple struct dereference trigger ARM hard_fault hardware exception

Tags: c, assembly, arm, cortex-m

I've been debugging this for many hours now. 
My application is an embedded program running on the CC2650 ARM M3 processor using the TI RTOS.

This line of c generates an ARM hard_fault exception (LD - link register set to 0xFFFFFFFD):

```
leaseStartMessageForReplay = *leaseStartMessage;
```

The code simply dereferences the `leaseStartMessage` struct pointer and copies the full struct content (2 words) to the `leaseStartMessageForReplay` struct. (Thats the intension at least).

The actual assembly for that line looks like this:
[image: assembly]

The assembly seems correct: 1st line loads R0 with the address of `leaseStartMessage`. 2nd line loads R2 with the address of the `leaseStartMessageForReplay`. 3rd line load the two words located at address-R0 into R0 and R2. 4th line stores the two words in R0 and R2 at address-R1.

The hard_fault exception happens on the 3rd line. The registers R0, R1, R2 have these values just before executing the 3rd instruction:
[image]

As can be seen the two address pointers R0 and R1 are initialized and I have verified that they contain the correct addresses.

Any help on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The surrounding code and variables declarations would be much more helpful than this whole dump of screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R0 isn't aligned to a 32 bit address, and LMDIA requires alignment.

Use memcpy() instead.

Comment: FWIW, the compiler shouldn't generate that instruction if your structure is marked as __packed

Comment: Well spotted. Thanks. I added __attribute__((__packed__)) to the struct definition and now it runs fine.

Comment: Just be aware that access to __packed structures will be slower (since it now assumes it's never aligned) and this could make a difference if you're accessing it in a tight loop.